# Logwatch does not report on httpd (apache2)

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, logwatch

Problem: I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 8  and my Logwatch does not have a "Begin httpd" section at all for my Apache pools.

/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logfiles/http.conf
is set for some custom files:

```
LogFile = apache2/*.log
```

Which I believe are being read, since grepping $ logwatch --debug 10, I can see "ADAMANTIUM" and all other custom log files, which are very standard Apache log files.

```
Logfile Name: http
   001-*applyhttpdate =
   000-*expandrepeats =
   Logfile = /var/log/apache2/ADAMANTIUM.log
   ...
   Preprocessing LogFile: http '/var/log/apache2/ADAMANTIUM.log'
```

In /usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf all the services are enabled:

```
Service = All
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... It looks like it just needed some time: I should not have been testing minutes after starting the new configuration. Which is the whole point of Logwatch: summaries, not real-time logging.